# DetailsView update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, detailsview

I have a GridView that shows all the registed users and some of their information and when you choose the "select" link off the side, it shows a DetailsView with all the details related to that user.  The select works fine and updates the details view for the selected user, and when I try to edit the DetailsView, it will update the database and fill in the information updated for ALL the users when changing the fields (eg. if I change the customers first name, everyone registered will get that name).  Here's my aspx code for my SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserProfile] ORDER BY [Email], [LastName], [Company]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [UserProfile] SET [LastName] = @LastName, [PartsList] = @PartsList, [UserName] = @UserName, [Question] = @Question, 
                      [Answer] = @Answer, [Role] = @Role 
                      WHERE [FirstName] = FirstName AND [Company] = Company">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PartsList" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Role" Type="String" />                    
            </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You forgot `@` for FirstName and Company, need `@FirstName` and `@Company`

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that, but now it doesn't update any value (single user or entire table).

Comment: Sorry you need `@original_FirstName` and `@original_Company`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `@original_` in your `Where` parameters

Change UpdateCommand to:

`UPDATE [UserProfile] SET [LastName] = @LastName, [PartsList] = @PartsList, [UserName] = @UserName, [Question] = @Question, 
                      [Answer] = @Answer, [Role] = @Role 
                      WHERE [FirstName] = @original_FirstName AND [Company] = @original_Company`